# Delphi getting records from sql using LIKE

Tags: sql, database, delphi, absolute-db

I am using a var that have a value add dynamically depending on what alphabet button is pressed. What I need it to do is get only the records of which the last name starts with that letter.

```pascal
Var
GetChar : String;
Begin
GetChar := GlobalVarUnit.AlphaValue;
RCMCListBox.Items.Clear;
RootsDB.Connected := True;
UpdateQuery.close;
UpdateQuery.SQL.Clear;
UpdateQuery.sql.text := 'SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE [PrimaryLastName] LIKE :CFind';
UpdateQuery.ParamCheck := True;
UpdateQuery.ParamByName('CFind').Value := GetChar;
UpdateQuery.open;
UpdateQuery.first;
RCMCListBox.Items.BeginUpdate;

//if GetChar <> '' then

while (not UpdateQuery.eof) and (UpdateQuery.ParamByName('CFind').Value = GetChar) do

begin
RCMCListBox.Items.Add(RCTable.fieldbyname('ContactID').asstring + ';' + RCTable.fieldbyname('CompanyName').asstring + ';'
+ RCTable.fieldbyname('PrimaryFirstName').asstring + ' ' + RCTable.fieldbyname('PrimaryLastName').asstring);
UpdateQuery.next;
RCMCListBox.Items.EndUpdate;
End;
UpdateQuery.Close;
RootsDB.Connected := False;
```

I have spent hours looking for a solution and I have been reading Cary Jensen's book on FireDac, most of what I find is using DB components to make this work. I really want to be able to do this with just SQL statements, I feel that gives the program more control as to when it's connected to the database to gather just what is need and then close it off when done.

I have also seen some conflicting ways of doing the following and I am not sure what is the right way.
For example:

```pascal
UpdateQuery.sql.text := 'SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE [PrimaryLastName] LIKE :CFind';
UpdateQuery.sql.text := 'SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE (PrimaryLastName) LIKE :CFind';
UpdateQuery.sql.text := 'SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE PrimaryLastName LIKE :CFind';
```

I am using Absolute Database.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1. [Edit] your question and specify what DBMS is being used. Depending on it different syntax and functions can be used.

Comment: 2. `LIKE :CFind` will return all rows, that contain symbol(s) from `:CFind` anywhere in `PrimaryLastName`. If you need specifically first letter, you'll need specify that in your request.

Comment: Your query will work as is if you change one line. Change `GetChar := GlobalVarUnit.AlphaValue;` to `GetChar := GlobalVarUnit.AlphaValue + '%'';` To match a partial string, you need a wildcard in your `LIKE` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @KenWhite mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76023693/delphi-getting-records-from-sql-using-like#comment134083911_76023693), your [`LIKE` clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) needs to use a wildcard pattern.

Also, you are performing the query with a component named `UpdateQuery`, but reading the field values from a component named `RCTable` instead.

Also, there is no need for your `while` loop to check the `CFind` parameter. And, you are misusing the `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` methods.

Try this instead:

```
var
  GetChar : String;
begin
  GetChar := GlobalVarUnit.AlphaValue;
  RCMCListBox.Items.Clear;
  RootsDB.Connected := True;
  try
    UpdateQuery.Close;
    UpdateQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE [PrimaryLastName] LIKE :CFind';
    UpdateQuery.ParamCheck := True;
    UpdateQuery.ParamByName('CFind').Value := GetChar + '%'; // <-- wildcard here
    UpdateQuery.Open;
    try
      UpdateQuery.First;
      RCMCListBox.Items.BeginUpdate;
      try
        while not UpdateQuery.Eof do
        begin 
          RCMCListBox.Items.Add(            
            UpdateQuery.FieldByName('ContactID').AsString + ';' +
            UpdateQuery.FieldByName('CompanyName').AsString + ';' +
            UpdateQuery.FieldByName('PrimaryFirstName').AsString + ' ' +
            UpdateQuery.FieldByName('PrimaryLastName').AsString
          );
          UpdateQuery.Next;
        end;
      finally
        RCMCListBox.Items.EndUpdate;
      end;
    finally
      UpdateQuery.Close;
    end;
  finally
    RootsDB.Connected := False;
  end;
```